# Psych alpha() function giving error when fed dplyr results

Tags: r, dplyr, psych

I have a large dataset that I am trying to trim down for focus. As part of it I have three variables that are measured at five times. I've made each time into a mean so I ended up with five variables (one for each time) which I want to find the internal consistency of. When I try to calculate Cronbach's alpha using `psych::alpha()` I get an error.

25 rows of reproducible data:

```
structure(list(catme_satis1a = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, NA, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L), catme_satis1b = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, NA, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L
), catme_satis1c = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, NA, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L), 
    catme_satis2a = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, NA, 5L, 4L, 5L, NA, 
    NA, 3L, NA, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, NA, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L
    ), catme_satis2b = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, NA, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
    NA, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, NA, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
    5L), catme_satis2c = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, NA, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
    NA, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, NA, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
    5L), catme_satis3a = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, NA, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L), catme_satis3b = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, NA, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L), catme_satis3c = c(4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, NA, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
    5L), catme_satis4a = c(4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L), catme_satis4b = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, NA, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L), catme_satis4c = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L), catme_satis5a = c(5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
    5L), catme_satis5b = c(5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
    5L), catme_satis5c = c(5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
    5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L), .Names = c("catme_satis1a", 
"catme_satis1b", "catme_satis1c", "catme_satis2a", "catme_satis2b", 
"catme_satis2c", "catme_satis3a", "catme_satis3b", "catme_satis3c", 
"catme_satis4a", "catme_satis4b", "catme_satis4c", "catme_satis5a", 
"catme_satis5b", "catme_satis5c"))
```

Next, I tried this to get the mean for columns 1:3, 4:6, etc. (but by name):

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- test %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  transmute(catme_satis1 = mean(c(catme_satis1a, catme_satis1b, catme_satis1c)),
            catme_satis2 = mean(c(catme_satis2a, catme_satis2b, catme_satis2c)),
            catme_satis3 = mean(c(catme_satis3a, catme_satis3b, catme_satis3c)),
            catme_satis4 = mean(c(catme_satis4a, catme_satis4b, catme_satis4c)),
            catme_satis5 = mean(c(catme_satis5a, catme_satis5b, catme_satis5c)))
```

Finally, I want to know the consistency of these variables using the `psych` package:

```
library(psych)
alpha(df1)
```

Which gives this error:

```
> alpha(df1)
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

My data frame seems to be correct when I print it, and I should be able to get the consistency of these values. Why is `r` throwing this error?

Comment: Try `alpha(as.data.frame(df1))`. `alpha` is expecting a `data.frame` or `matrix`. `class(df1)` is `"rowwise_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"`.

Comment: After some exploration I figured this out and was going to answer my own question. You got me right in the middle of my posts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some exploration I found a way to make this work. It involves the `dplyr` output having additional classes beyond `data.frame`. I created the mean columns in a different manner to keep things away from `dplyr` using the following code (note that this one is named `df2` to facilitate comparison later on):

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  catme_satis1 = apply(test[, 1:3], 1, mean),
  catme_satis2 = apply(test[, 4:6], 1, mean),
  catme_satis3 = apply(test[, 7:9], 1, mean),
  catme_satis4 = apply(test[, 10:12], 1, mean),
  catme_satis5 = apply(test[, 13:15], 1, mean)
)
```

The `alpha(df2)` command worked just fine. This inspired me to check a few things about the dataframes.
The class of `df1` from my original post, and `df2` here is different:

```
> class(df1)
[1] "rowwise_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> class(df2)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Also, they recognized as being completely identical *unless I coerce the dplyr output to be a dataframe!*

```
> identical(df1, df2)
[1] FALSE
> identical(as.data.frame(df1), df2)
[1] TRUE
```

Running the command `alpha(as.data.frame(df1))` works and produces identical results. There are two solutions here:

1. Use non `dplyr` methods to get the mean data. This keeps the data as a data.frame classed object.
2. Use `as.data.frame()` to coerce the object into the right class when running the `alpha()` function. Or add `%>% as.data.frame()` to the end of the `dplyr` mutate command.